# Seeking advice/suggestion for TABLE strcutures for POS and inventory system in laravel

Tags: laravel, inventory, pos

Hi I would like to ask for your suggestions and advice regarding with how to design an effective table structure for my current Laravel project. The project is POS with inventory. With your help I already done with the other minor parts such as the roles, user mngt, etc. I am now at the heart of the project which is the creating Purchase order and invoice system. I am new with creating/designing database tables because most of my works are wordpress development only.

My worries are I might waste so much time if I mess up the table structures that’s why I decided to ask for your suggestions.

Here’s the flow of the items,

Stocks/items will only receive by WAREHOUSE 1 through PURCHASE ORDERS. Then WAREHOUSE 1 will transfer the stocks to WAREHOUSE 2 for sales. So the invoice will look stocks/items in warehouse 2 only.

The expected reports by my boss are:

Remaining Products per warehouse like

Products | warehouse 1 | warehouse 2
Bottles  |  300        | 200 
Labels   |  150        | 0


List of products with remaining stocks

Product Code|Product Name|Supplier Name|Category|remaining stocks|action

Once the history (will be located in action) clicked, the product trailing record will appear.

Product trailing report like

Supplier | Customer | Stock-In |Stock-Out | P.O/Inv number

```
For purchasing and invoicing I am planning to put them in single table;
po_invc_num (P.O or invoice #)</br>
rcv_by_warehouse (either 1 or 2)</br>
rcv_by_user</br>
prod_code</br>
sup_cust_id (supplier and customer’s ID. I already have table and I already have CRUD for this)</br>
quantity</br>
tot_amnt</br>
notes</br>
```

I already have my products table and working CRUD for this:

```
id</br>
product_code</br>
name</br>
categories_id</br>
wh1_limit_warning</br>
wh2_limit_warning</br>
price</br>
selling_price</br>
user_id</br>
created_at</br>
```

it puzzles me on how will i able to achieve the this part

```
Products | warehouse 1 | warehouse 2
Bottles | 300 | 200
Labels | 150 | 0
```

and the other reports by just receiving the P.O.

any suggestions and advice will so much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Designing a database can be subjective. But few rules you can follow :

1. Normalise your tables so that each entity represents a particular domain model. For example for an order, you have product details, quantity and order addresses etc. Having this entirely in one table is not a good practice. You can have:
2. Products table with all product details
3. Customers table with customer details
4. Addresses table which has customer_id reference to know which address belongs to which customer
5. Orders table with order detail and references to customers using customer_id, addresses for billing/shipping address using address_id
6. Order_Items table to show which products in particular order. So you can use product_id to reference products, order_id to reference order, quantity price

Please note this is just an idea of how you can design scalable and effective normalised structure for simple order. Then it also depends upon how you query the data effectively and how you index to determine optimisation levels.

Again, if you want to avoid brainstorming on this, there are packages available for laravel ecommerce.

- [vanilo](https://vanilo.io/)
- [aimeos](https://aimeos.org/laravel-ecommerce-package/)
- [bagisto](https://bagisto.com/en/)

and some more you can find on packagist or github

Comment: Thank you @Mihir!! really appreciate your suggestions!

Comment: Happy to help @LitoLozada :)